# Accessing custom cell attributes outside of cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I want some thing like image below. User can click on + or - button and the increased or decreased count is display in UILabel i.e 1 in the image below.
I know how to implement custom table view cell .I know how to implement the selector too. but I need to set the label text according as the button clicked thats only is the problem .
How can I **update button clicked**  and **set text of UILabel** of custom cell **outside  from cellForRowAtIndexPathwith** add subtract features.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

     static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ProductListVIICell";

     ProductListVIICell *cell = (ProductListVIICell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
         NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProductListVIICell" owner:self options:nil];
         cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
     } ....................................
        cell.btnMinus.tag = indexPath.row;
        cell.btnPlus.tag = indexPath.row;

        [cell.btnPlus addTarget:self action:@selector(addItem:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.btnMinus addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteItem:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        cell.lblCount.tag = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d",addBtnClickCount,addBtnClickCount] integerValue];


        return cell;
    }
```

I need to do things here but didnt get what I want to acheive. `cell.lblTitle.text` isnt working

```
  #pragma mark - UIButton selector

-(void)addItem:(UIButton*)button {
    itemCount++;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:button.tag inSection:1];
    ProductListVIICell *cell = (ProductListVIICell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
      cell.lblCount.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
     cell.lblTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",itemCount];

    NSIndexPath* rowToReload = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[button tag] inSection:0];
    NSArray* rowsToReload = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rowToReload, nil];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
     NSLog(@"%d",itemCount);
    [self.tableView reloadData];


}

-(void)deleteItem:(UIButton*)button {
    itemCount--;
     NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:button.tag inSection:1];
    ProductListVIICell *cell = (ProductListVIICell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.lblCount.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    cell.lblTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",itemCount];

    NSIndexPath* rowToReload = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[button tag] inSection:0];
    NSArray* rowsToReload = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rowToReload, nil];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
     NSLog(@"%d",itemCount);
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

[image]

**These links are useful too**

[Accessing cell attributes outside of cellForRowAtIndexPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16220777/accessing-cell-attributes-outside-of-cellforrowatindexpath)

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/blocks-and-table-view-cells-on-ios--mobile-22982
but it is only for UITableViewCell not the custom cell

**I was able to solve my problem using following**

```
@interface ProductListVC ()
{
    int count;
    bool addBtnClicked;
    bool minusBtnClicked;


}

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray* quantityArray; //stores label
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray* quantityLabelArray; //stores label

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    _quantityLabelArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     _quantityArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//determine num of row prevent index 2 beyond bounds for empty array error i.e insert straight to let's say index 3
    for (int i=0; i <=[_productArray count]; i++) {
            [_quantityArray addObject:@"0"];

        }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
................

if (!_quantityArray || !_quantityArray.count){
        cell.lblCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 0];

    }else{
        cell.lblCount.text = [_quantityArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     }
     [_quantityLabelArray addObject:cell.lblCount];


    if (addBtnClicked || minusBtnClicked) {
        //If add or minu button is reloading the cell

        cell.lblCount.text = [_quantityArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        //NSLog(@"%@",cell.lblCount.text);
        [_quantityLabelArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:cell.lblCount];
        addBtnClicked = NO;
        minusBtnClicked = NO;

    }
    else
    {

    }

    cell.btnMinus.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.btnPlus.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.lblCount.tag = indexPath.row;

    [cell.btnPlus addTarget:self action:@selector(addItem:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.btnMinus addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteItem:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;
}



#pragma mark - UIButton selector

-(void)addItem:(UIButton*)button

{

     NSLog(@"btn tag %ld",(long)[button tag]);
     NSLog(@"quantitylblarry %@",_quantityLabelArray);

        UILabel* lblShowCount = [_quantityLabelArray objectAtIndex:[button tag]];
        if ([lblShowCount.text integerValue]< 10) {
            count = count+1;
            lblShowCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", [lblShowCount.text integerValue]+1];
        }

     NSLog(@"quantity array count %lu",(unsigned long)_quantityArray.count);

        if (_quantityArray.count > [button tag] ) {

            [_quantityArray removeObjectAtIndex:[button tag]];
            [_quantityArray insertObject:lblShowCount.text atIndex:[button tag]];
        }

        else{

            [_quantityArray insertObject:lblShowCount.text atIndex:[button tag]];
        }
        addBtnClicked = YES;

        NSLog(@"quantity array %@",_quantityArray);
        NSIndexPath* rowToReload = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[button tag] inSection:0];
        NSArray* rowsToReload = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rowToReload, nil];
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

    }





-(void)deleteItem:(UIButton*)button{

     NSLog(@"%ld",(long)[button tag]);
    UILabel* lblShowCount = [_quantityLabelArray objectAtIndex:[button tag]];


        if ([lblShowCount.text integerValue]>=1) {
            count = count-1;
            lblShowCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", [lblShowCount.text integerValue]-1];

        }

        NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)_quantityArray.count);

        if (_quantityArray.count > [button tag] ) {
            [_quantityArray removeObjectAtIndex:[button tag]];
            [_quantityArray insertObject:lblShowCount.text atIndex:[button tag]];
        }
        else{
            [_quantityArray insertObject:lblShowCount.text atIndex:[button tag]];

        }
        NSLog(@"%@",_quantityArray);
        minusBtnClicked =YES;

        NSLog(@"quantity array %@",_quantityArray);
        NSIndexPath* rowToReload = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[button tag] inSection:0];
        NSArray* rowsToReload = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rowToReload, nil];
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

 }
```

Comment: you should see this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652133/how-to-set-action-for-uibutton-in-uitableviewcell ..i have done in swift but not in objective c...

Comment: i know Action for UIButton in UITableViewCell  but problem is to set the UILabel every time user click the button

Comment: cell.lblTitle.text ="value changed"; does this work?everything you are doing seems correct

Comment: nopes it doesnt work out

Answer (score 2):

it is better to use custom cell. Check this [tutorials](http://www.pumpmybicep.com/2014/07/21/designing-a-custom-uitableviewcell-in-interface-builder/) or this [one](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-customize-uitableview-storyboard/), then you will need to add delegate to this cell so that you can sync quantities with you ViewController

i.e.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.delegate = self;
    cell.itemIndex = indexPath.row;
    ....
    return cell
}
```

**UPDATE**

if you have a custom cell, you would add an `UILabel` outlet and modify its text in the action of `+/-` buttons, all this code will be in `CustomTableViewCell.m`

```
-(void)addItem:(UIButton*)button {    
    self.itemQuantity++; 
    [self updateQuantity];
}

-(void)deleteItem:(UIButton*)button {
    self.itemQuantity--;
    [self updateQuantity];
}
- (void)updateQuantity{
    self.lblCount.text = [NSStirng stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.itemQuantity];
    [self.delegate updateItemAtIndex:self.itemIndex withQuantity:self.itemQuantity];
}
```

**UPDATE: COMPLETE SOLUTION**

**1. Model**

```
@interface Item : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger quantity;
@end

@implementation Item

@end
```

**2. Custom Cell**

```
@interface CustomItemTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *lblTitle;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *lblCount;
@property (nonatomic, assign) Item *item;
@end

@implementation CustomItemTableViewCell

- (void)updateCellWithItem:(Item *)item {
    self.item = item;
    [self updateCellView];
}
- (void)updateCellView {
    self.lblTitle.text = self.item.title;
    self.lblTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", self.item.quantity];
}
- (IBAction)addItem:(UIButton*)button {
    self.item.quantity++;
    [self updateCellView];
}

- (IBAction)deleteItem:(UIButton*)button {
    self.item.quantity--;
    [self updateCellView];
}

@end
```

**3. TableViewController**

```
@interface ItemsTableViewController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *items;
@end

@implementation ItemsTableViewController

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.items.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CustomItemTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomItemCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell updateCellWithItem:self.items[indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I know how to implement custom table view cell . Can u check the question once again . I know how to implement the selector too. but i need to increase and decrease the label text according as the button clicked thats only is the problem

Comment: if you have a custom cell, you would add an `UILabel` outlet and modify its text in the action of `+/-` buttons, all this code will be in `CustomTableViewCell.m`

Comment: So you moved the code the the CustomCell class? Are you sure you added the outlet and defined the delegate in the .h file?

Comment: Currently I have upvote u for ur effort  and Thanks alot

Comment: i have still gt the trouble can u check the edited question please

Comment: I have added complete solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81623/discussion-between-nischal-hada-and-mahmoud-adam).

Comment: I followed the UPDATE: COMPLETE SOLUTION but the text was just set to 0 and it doesnt work dude

Comment: can u check this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31158404/how-to-add-check-box-in-custom-table-view-cell/31158493#31158493

Answer (score 0):

To change the cell label text you need to extract the cell object in those selectors, which you can do simply by using the sender parameter, in your case a button. See the code below for add functionality.

```
-(void)addItem:(UIButton*) button
{    
  NSLog(@"UIButton%ld",(long)button.tag);
  addBtnClickCount++;  //Increase the count by 1
  MyCustomCell *cell = button.superview.superview;
  //Now change the label text for cell
  cell.lblCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",addBtnClickCount];
}
```

Same way you can do for subtract functionality.

Comment: do u really think it can be done cell.lblCount.text  outside from cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: I haven't tried it myself. But it should as you are just modifying the cell object. Just try it once.

Comment: can u check my modified questions

Comment: why are you calculating the indexPath for section 1 in your `addItem:` method. I do not see any section in images or the in the code of `cellForRow...`. Maybe that is the reason. I have tested my logic now and it works, so something else might be in play. Try to use debugger. Print all the cell objects in your table view and then print the cell what you got in `addItem:` method and see if they are same object.

Comment: what is the use of     [cell updateCellWithItem:self.items[indexPath.row]];

Answer (score 0):

use steeper control in custom tableview cell.

[this is my screen.i used stepper control and label.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Myfq.png)

**customcell.h class**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIStepper *stepper;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl_value;
```

****customcell.m****

```
- (IBAction)stepper:(UIStepper *)sender {
    NSUInteger value = sender.value;
    lbl_value.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%03d",value];
    self.txt1.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%03d",value];

}
```