# How to get label value in table view cell on button click in cell

Tags: ios, swift

I have a prototype cell which with a button and a label in it. The text of the label changes for each cell. I have set up an `@IBAction` for the button and would like to get the text for the label in the cell in which the button in pressed. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: does any one can answer this similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31049551/accessing-custom-cell-attributes-outside-of-cellforrowatindexpath

Answer (score 0):

1. In didSelectRowAtIndexPath method you can get selected cell using 
   cellForRowAtIndexPath using indexPath.row
2. when you get selected cell object you can access that label which present inside the cell.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: does any one can answer this similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31049551/accessing-custom-cell-attributes-outside-of-cellforrowatindexpath

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)buttonHandler:(id)sender{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)button.superview;
    println("%@",cell.textLabel.text)
}
```

Comment: does any one can answer this similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31049551/accessing-custom-cell-attributes-outside-of-cellforrowatindexpath